# code igniter sql server when in different pc get error sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Tags: php, codeigniter-2, sql-server-2014

I want to connect code igniter. I am using :

- code igniter version 2.1.3
- PHP Version 5.6.15
- SQL Server 2014
- windows 10
- php info : Thread Safety enabled

When i install all in same pc, code igniter can conect to sql server. 
But when i move code igniter to different pc, i am get error like bellow :

> Message: sqlsrv_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean
>   given

Here that i do with client PC:

- I already install "ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server" in client pc, if i test using "ODBC Data Source" Test is success.
- i add into C:\xampp\php\php.ini 
  extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
  extension=php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
- i put below file in folder C:\xampp\php\ext
  php_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
  php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll

With all above, i am still getting this error.

Comment: Formatting messages, list items

Comment: Thanks for help, i already found the solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

After several day, i already found how to solve the problem. Here my step:
1. i uninstall ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
2. Then i download Microsoft® ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server from this link 
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36434
3. then i install ODBC Driver 11

Hope this help another that have same problem. :)